# How to put a value from array to another list in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, list

Can anyone help me, guys?
this foreach is always error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
even though I have given index 0, what's the solution

```
var store = _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart == entity.id_cart).ToList();
                    int index = -1;
           
                    foreach (var cart in store)
                    {
                        var b = index++; // it shows 
                        entity.cart[0].nama_produk = cart.nama_produk;

                        entity.cart[0].jumlah = cart.jumlah;
                        entity.cart[0].harga = cart.harga;
                        entity.cart[0].subtotal = cart.subtotal;
                        entity.cart[0].notes = cart.notes;
                    }
```

here is the class object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DD2s.png)

I think I declared the entity cart array / list incorrectly, do you know the correct method?
please dont be mean im a newbie

Comment: `entity.cart[0]` will work **if** there is at least one item in the `entity.cart` list/array.

Comment: But there is also a likely logic error as you are using the same index `0` in a loop which means you are accessing the same item every time.

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: ^-- Learning how to do this will save you a great deal of time and is something any developer regardless of experience should learn how to do.

Comment: yes i think thats correct, can you tell me how should i do it ????

Comment: It would help if you can post more code.
For example, what is type entity. Or _cartCollection

Comment: wait a minute ..

Comment: @JoeStarbright i think thats all of the code, basically the store variable is the source array that i use in the foreach and i want to put the value from store array / variable into the entity.cart[] but i dont know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your exact issue is here, but I see a few "code smells" that might be causing the issue:

1. In this code block:

   ```
    var store = _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart == entity.id_cart).ToList();
    int index = -1;
    foreach (var cart in store)
   ```

It seems that you are retrieving a **single** cart based on its ID and then doing something with it.  If I have that right, you can accomplish this much more simply with something like this:

```
    var cart = _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart == entity.id_cart).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you don't need the for loop at all... just use the one cart you found.
On that note, you should also probably check **cart** for null... in case it doesn't exist... but that is up to your specific use case.

2. index is being incremented for each step in the loop... but its value is never used.  Unless you have a reason to use it, I recommend just deleting it entirely... unless you intended to retrieve multiple carts and add them all to the entity.cart collection.
3. In this code block (which is what is actually throwing the error:

   ```
                    entity.cart[0].nama_produk = cart.nama_produk;

                    entity.cart[0].jumlah = cart.jumlah;
                    entity.cart[0].harga = cart.harga;
                    entity.cart[0].subtotal = cart.subtotal;
                    entity.cart[0].notes = cart.notes;
   ```

The code is not clear.  My best guess at what you are trying to do is to add the details of the cart you found to a collection of cart information on the entity object.  I also assume that entity.cart is a List or something like that.

If my assumptions are correct, then the reason you are getting the reason you are getting that exception is the cart[0] doesn't exist until you add a cart object to that list (which is probably what you are trying to do here.  A more readable (and less error prone) way to do this would be:

```
       var entityCart = new Cart {
                                     nama_produk = cart.nama_produk,
                                     jumlah = cart.jumlah,
                                     harga = cart.harga,
                                     subtotal = cart.subtotal,
                                     notes = cart.notes
                                 };
       entity.cart.Add(entityCart);
```

It could be that you are trying to add products to a cart... in that case, you should change your variable names a bit, but the rest is very similar.

Comment: what is cart in the " var entityCart = new Cart " ?

Comment: and it is not FirstOrDefault, i put it toList because i want to get a list of data and loop it using foreach

Comment: #kina  If you expect the query to return a list, the foreach is good.... Just replace the inner piece with the object creation (I made up the class name... but you can put in the correct class) and use Add